# PHP - Query doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

So I got code which gets row from database, but it doesn't seem to work :/.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM steam_users WHERE steamid='$steamid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    print_r($row['tradeurl']);
}
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" doesn't tell us much. Which errors do you get? Also you should stop using the mysql_* functions, the entire api is removed from PHP 7. Use PDO or Mysqli instead.

Comment: I don't get any errors

Comment: Then what do you get? And how does that differ from what you were expecting to get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Looks like you have the $steamid in quotes which turns it into a string, which is !== integer.

Answer (score 1):

Could be quotes problem try

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM steam_users WHERE steamid='" . $steamid "';");
```